# C#, ASP.NET Core Blazor, TouchEventArgs has no OffsetX

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, skiasharp

In C#, ASP.NET Core, Blazor I am using SKGLView and can click on in with a mouse event listener, it works great.

Now, I want to touch on it with a touch event listener, it works, but the touch coordinate is not working well, and that because touch event do not have OffsetX & OffsetY like mouse event to.

I can only choose between PageX, ScreenX and ClientX and all of them return the same value, and seems to be offset from the browser left and top corner.

```
<SKGLView 
     @ontouchstart="touchstart" @ontouchmove="touchmove" @ontouchend="touchend"
     @onmousedown="mousedown" @onmousemove="mousemove" 
     @onmouseup="mouseup" @onwheel="mousewheel" />
```

Mouse event handler:

```
private void mousedown(MouseEventArgs args)
{
    m_mouseDown = true;

    TouchLocation pos = new TouchLocation(0, args.OffsetX * m_dpiScale, args.OffsetY * m_dpiScale, TouchLocationState.Pressed);
}
```

Touch event handler:

```
private void touchstart(TouchEventArgs args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.TargetTouches.Length; i++)
    {
        var touch = args.TargetTouches[i];
        var px = touch.ClientX * m_dpiScale;
        var py = touch.ClientY * m_dpiScale;
        TouchLocation pos = new TouchLocation((int)touch.Identifier, px, py, TouchLocationState.Pressed);
    }
}
```

MouseEventArgs has:

```
ScreenX
PageX
ClientX
OffsetX
```

TouchEventArgs has:

```
ScreenX
PageX
ClientX
```

But no `OffsetX`. Why are `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` missing? How can I make my touch event be like mouse events?

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, you might be looking at the wrong set of EventArgs. `@ontouchstart` is the touch-screen equivalent of `@onmousedown` or (almost) `@onclick`, and therefore it only sends data for that touch. You may instead be looking for `@ondrag` which fires the [`DragEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.drageventargs?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which contains what you're looking for; the `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` properties.

The difference between the `@ontouchstart` and `@ondrag` is that `@ontouchstart` would mainly used for single tap or tap and hold handling, since if it counted a drag every time someone had their finger on the screen and moved even a pixel, there would be a lot more issues to solve, so `@ondrag` is fired when an adequate distance is measured after the initial tap. Hope this helps!